# Display different content to every 100th page visitor (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, session

I have a client who would like a landing page to display a specific coupon code to every nth user that will give them access to a prize. I've looked into a few different options, but most are based on a period of time or user account permissions, and not user sessions. I've also read that Wordpress doesn't handle sessions well?

Looking for suggestions and possible solutions. Thanks!

Comment: You can save user counter in db. When user enter site, need to check cookie with some unique value. If he has cookie do nothing, else add cookie and increment value in db. When counter is 100 show coupon.